# Nested entity models query issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i have 3 nested models: ApplicationUser(from entity framework), City and State.
ApplicationUser has city as foreign key and city has state as foreign key.
When I query a user, i get a user with all of its attributes including City as a related model but when i lookup into city, the related model State is null, all the others attributes are ok. Any clue?

This is StateModels

```
public class StateModels
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    }
```

This is CityModels

```
public class CityModels
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
        public virtual StateModels State { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public virtual CityModels City { get; set; }
        public string CompanyPhone { get; set; }
        public string CompanyFax { get; set; }
        public bool Validated { get; set; }
        public bool Staff { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

This is how i try to get to the state object

```
ApplicationUser applicationUser = db.Users.Find(idUser);
var city = applicationUser.City; //object city is ok
var state = city.State; // this field is null, all others attributes are ok
```

In the db, all city registers have state id reference

Answer (score 0):

Try this. db.Users.Find(idUser).Include(u=>u.City).Include(u=>u.City.State) and make sure you have all foreign keys are properly set.